# How can I access the state of a Provider component within the (parent) component that instantiates the Provider component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have implemented a React "Provider" component to share a reducer within a component hierarchy. Following the [example in React's latest tutorial](https://react.dev/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context#moving-all-wiring-into-a-single-file), I implement the provider using React Context and the `useReducer` hook:

```
export function CourseProvider ({children, initialCourse})  {
    const [course, dispatch] = useReducer(courseChangeReducer, initialCourse);
    return (
        <CourseContext.Provider value={course}>
            <CourseDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
                {children}
            </CourseDispatchContext.Provider>
        </CourseContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

As recommended in the tutorial, I make the state variable and dispatch function available through custom hooks:

```
export function useCourse() {
    return useContext(CourseContext);
}

export function useCourseDispatch() {
    return useContext(CourseDispatchContext);
}
```

To make the state variable and reducer available throughout the component hierarchy, I wrap the parent component's JSX render code inside the `<CourseProvider>` component:

```
return(
  <CourseProvider initialCourse={currentCourse}>
    <section>
      <h1 className="centered">{course.shortName}</h1>
      {/* Rendering details snipped */}
        <div className="mode-page-btn-container">
            <button className="dialog-primary-btn"
                ref={saveChangesBtn}
                type="button" onClick={()=>closeCourseDetails(course)}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon="save"/>&nbsp;Save Changes 
            </button>
        {/* Rendering details snipped */}
    </section> 
  </CourseProvider>
);
```

As you can see, the parent component's rendering code needs access to the latest value of the `course` state variable used by the `<CourseProvider>` component that is instantiated within its rendering code. To gain access to the `course` state variable, I thought that I could make use of the custom `useCourse` hook in the parent `CoursesModeDetails` component:

```
import { useCourse, CourseProvider } from './CourseContext';
...
export default function CourseModeDetails({currentCourse, closeCourseDetails}) {
  const course = useCourse();
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately, no matter what I have tried, the `course` variable's value is always `null`. It does not appear to update in response to actions dispatched by the `CoursesModeDetails` component's children.

So my question is simple: How can I access the most up-to-date value of the `course` variable in the parent `CoursesModeDetails` component? Accessing that value is necessary not only to render the component, but also to update its parent component's state (via the `closeCourseDetails` function prop).

Answer (score 0):

Split the `section` into a separate component that uses the context via `useCourse()`:

```
const Section = ({ closeCourseDetails }) => {
  const course = useCourse();

  return(
    <section>
      <h1 className="centered">{course.shortName}</h1>
      {/* Rendering details snipped */}
        <div className="mode-page-btn-container">
          <button className="dialog-primary-btn"
              ref={saveChangesBtn}
              type="button" onClick={()=>closeCourseDetails(course)}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon="save"/>&nbsp;Save Changes 
          </button>
        {/* Rendering details snipped */}
    </section> 
  );
};
```

And then render it in the parent:

```
const Parent = () => {
  ...
  
  return (
    <CourseProvider initialCourse={currentCourse}>
      <Section closeCourseDetails={closeCourseDetails} />
    </CourseProvider>
  );
}
```